# rails 3, checkbox from table database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

how to create a list of checkboxes from a table of the database in my case I have a table Employees who need a type of employee assigned example:

```
select * from type_employeed
```

generate:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='1'> Vendedor
<input type='checkbox' value='2'> Proveedor
<input type='checkbox' value='3'> Jefe de zona
<input type='checkbox' value='4'> Manejador
```

Comment: many junk code and no usefull info

Comment: ok now the question corrected

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But in general, this is the way to go, to use check boxes.

Suppose, you have a field in your model Post, say `:allow_comment`. So, in your **modal form**, it would look like this

```
<%= f.check_box :allow_comment %>
```

If you want a default value for your checkbox, you should set the value of that field to 0 or 1 in your controller. So, in the **new** action of your controller **PostsController**, you would write,

```
@post.allow_comment = 1 # will set the default value of check box at 1
```

To learn more on check boxes, watch [Ryan Bates' Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)